# Django SMTP [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, django, smtp

I am trying to send email from a web app using django and a sendgrid SMTP server. It works fine locally but when I try to use it on pythonanywhere I get

```
error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

The code from the relevant view is

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmailForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            mail = form.cleaned_data

            send_mail(
                'Automated Enquiry',
                'A user is interested in part ' + mail['part'] + '.Their message: ' + mail['msg'],
                mail['email'],
                ['myemail@gmail.com'],
                fail_silently = False,
            )

            return render(request, 'manager/error.html', {'msg': "Thanks, we will be in touch as soon as possible"})

    else:
        part = request.GET.get('part', '')
        form = EmailForm()

    return render(request, 'manager/contact.html', {'form': form, 'part':part})
```

And in my setting.py:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.sendgrid.net'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myuser'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

It didn't work from the console either.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try to telnet smtp server from console

Comment: I tried telnet smtp.sendgrid.net 587 and got telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused @chakri

Comment: I just googled it and that was the issue, I should have checked before asking, thanks a lot. @chakri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

free users on PythonAnywhere have restricted Internet access to a [whitelist](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/) of sites, and only the HTTP/HTTPS protocols are allowed, so you cannot make SMTP connections to sendgrid from a free account.

you can use gmail from a free account, and pythonanywhere have [instructions here](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/SMTPForFreeUsers).

or you can switch to using the sandgrid HTTP api:  https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/django.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am planning on upgrading to hacker account soon anyway, will that resolve this issue?

Comment: yes, it should do.  send an email to support@ if you need any more help!